# gm for node.js: resize only if image is bigger then target size

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphicsmagick

I do a resize to make huge images fit to the website, that means big files are shrinked to 1000px.

```
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('1000').stream().pipe(writeStream);
```

But how can I avoid that tiny images get bigger?

Comment: Simply use '1000>' instead of '1000'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gm's `size` method:

```
var image = gm(readStream, fileObj.name());
image.size(function(err, size){
  if(size.width >= 1000 && size.height >= 1000) {
    image.resize('1000').stream().pipe(writeStream);
  }
})
```